# Executing node function for each line in txt file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a list of items i am trying to call a function for each item. There is a name and a price on each line and I am trying to set them as variables for a function.

i am able to list through the items but I cant call a function with each individually. This is what I have but cant figure it out. Thanks!

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input : fs.createReadStream('./items/item.txt'),
      output: process.stdout,
      terminal: false
})
rl.on('line',function(line){
     console.log(line) //or parse line
     for(i in line){
        //do action!

     }
})
```

Comment: Well, a for-in loop probably [doesn't do what you think](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). It iterates through properties of an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(i in line){
     //pass
 }
```

returns characters of string for this line

if your lines are formatted like
`foobar 1.23`, you can explode on space

```
rl.on('line', function(line){

     var item = line.split(' ');
     var itemName = item[0];
     var itemPrice = item[1];
     doAction(itemName, itemPrice);
})
```

or using a RegExp with Capturing Groups

or maybe using another format; for every line like JSON

Comment: thanks for the response, but isnt that going to doAction() all at once? Doesnt it need to be a loop of some sort? thnaks

Comment: with `on('line'`, callback is called for each line of your file

Answer (score 0):

you can try in this wayyou can try it as following:

```
const items = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, file), 'utf-8').split('\n');

items.forEach((item) => {
    // do your action
    let name = item.split('--')[0];
    let price = item.split('--')[1]
})
```